# How to write Ruby hash with list keys in YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

Say I have:

```
h = {}
h[["one", "two"]] = "three"
# h = {["one", "two"]=>"three"}
```

How do I represent the above hash in YAML such that `YAML.load_file('that_file')` will load the `h` hash correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_yaml` method to preview this:

```
h = {}
h[["one", "two"]] = "three"
h.to_yaml
# => "---\n? - one\n  - two\n: three\n"
```

Comment: I use this technique to generate YAML for big configuration files. It is very convenient and efficient.